# how to close outlook application from the AddIn of the outlook using c#?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Is it possible to close the outlook form from the outlook AddIn using c# Ribbon AddIn. Where can we get the handle to the outlook form to close it?

Answer (score 0):

"Form" as in "Outlook Inspector"? Call Inspector.Close. The active Outlook inspector can be retrieved from Application.ActiveInspector.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain with more details that, what you want? The first of all you can use `Application.Quit()` and you can kill Outlook process if need.

```
        Process processToKill = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            if(processToKill != null)
            {
                process.Kill();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
```